# Excel Formula to do: If Value A is in B, Match Value A from C

Tags: excel

Ok so I'm very confused with Excel.

I have 3 columns A, B, C.

B and C go together, for example: [B1]=1 [C1]= "B1s value is 1".

Column A has values for 400,000 rows, Column B has values for 1000 rows and subsequently column C has 1000 corresponding values to column B.

For each row in column A I want to check to see if any of the values from column B match, if they do, I want the value from column C to be aligned with column A.

So, I'm checking column B against A and, if they match, I want the corresponding value from column C. If they don't have a match just a blank value instead. I hope this makes sense. Ive been stuck on this for a while now, please help me out.

*update example:

so imagine column a has 460,000 entries b and c have about a thousand and they are paired together. so for each of a check to see if any of b match then if they do I want the value from column c]
[[image: [1]]

Comment: can you include an example of your data? What kind of values are in column A, would it be used as a lookup column?

Comment: ok i will update

Comment: Now you need to show the results you expect so we can understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Im trying to get the results i dont have a visual example yet. basically look at the pic and column a1 value is wl-svc then look at column B somewhere in the 1000 entries for column b is wl-svc and next to it in column c would be some text like "netserver". So thats what I need for each of the 460,000 entries in column a, I dont know how else to explain it

Comment: an example would be if b9 = a1 then i want c9 in d1

Answer (score 1):

In cell D1:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$2000,MATCH(A1,B$1:B$2000,0)),"")
```

Then copy down

Answer (score 1):

You can put a countif and a vlookup together to find it.

The countif will find if the result from A is found in B. If so, the Vlookup will then find the corresponding C value to return:

```
=if(COUNTIF(B:B;A1)>0;vlookup(A1;B:C;2;0);"")
```